# How to interpret and constrain the 'bias' from an OLS multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares

I'm trying to solve a linear system with OLS and understand how the output coefficients deviate from the input values of mock data. The basic ideas are as follows.

1. For the linear system `Y = [b1, b2, b3, ..., bn] [X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn]^T`, I specify a fixed vector `[X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn]` for both data making and model fitting.
2. I then assign coefficients `0 < b1_i < b2_i < b3_i < ... < bn_i` and perturb the products (`bn_i Xn`) according to a lognormal distribution with scatter S dex. The sum of the perturbed products gives the mock Y.
3. Run OLS to solve for the coefficients `b1_o, b2_o, b3_o, ..., bn_o`.

When the scatter *S* is negligible, the output agrees with the input pretty well as expected. However, as *S* increases, discrepancy starts to show up, in particular for terms with very small b's (note that X's are of similar order of magnitude). The larger the dynamic range of input b's, the larger bias will be observed in those small b outputs.

Apparently, OLS is neither the only nor the best way to do this. As the small terms are of great interest in our model, we're thinking about how those coefficients can be constrained better (i.e. reducing their bias somehow, if possible), but I'm not clear what else approach I should turn to. So any advice on this will be really appreciated!